# Using Android Data Binding, how to specify a dummy (or "default") text to be displayed during layout preview in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-databinding

Can I specify a string to be shown in the layout preview in Android studio, e.g. for a TextView? ( Lorem ipsum ...)

It would be very helpful to be able to do that to see some text in the layout editor, e.g. to see if the textsize is correct etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found the answer myself just now:

## Option 1:

```
android:text="@{user.name, default=JOHN_DOE}"
```

As explained at the very bottom of this page:

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/data-binding/guide.html

Drawback:  Not sure how to use strings with spaces.

## Option 2

http://tools.android.com/tips/layout-designtime-attributes

1.) Add tools namespace in your root node:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

2.) Add a tools:text attribute:

```
 <TextView
        tools:text="John Doe"
```

Drawback: You need to add the tools namespace to your root node.

Comment: With regards to option 1. You should be able to use text with spaces if you use single quotes on the outside and double quotes around the text only.

Comment: @Jeffrey Either that or use backticks `for strings inside the expression

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `tools:text`

Add the tools namespace to your root element.

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Then the tools:text attribute as below.

[image]

Whether you are using `DataBinding` or not it doesn't matter, `tools:text` will work to see text during layout preview.

For more info see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes

Answer (score -4):

Yes you can, for example on a TextView :

```
android:text="Lorem ipsum"
```

Comment: Won't work since that same attribute is where the binding is defined : android:text="@{user.name}"

Comment: No worries, edited the title to be more clear now. Thanks!